# How to autofill the next row of a DataTable, using Excel technology?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I have a `System.Data.DataTable`, containing some entries, and I would like to predict the following tupple(s).

I'm now experimenting with `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`, and I have created the following piece of source code:

```
#region Excel
  Application xlApp = new Application(); // Excel application
  Workbook xlWorkBook;                   // Excel workbook, just temporary
  Worksheet xlWorkSheet;                 // Excel worksheet, also just temporary
  object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

  xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
  xlWorkSheet = (Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

  for (int i = 0; i < dt_main.Columns.Count; i++) // Fill in title of columns
  { xlWorkSheet.Cells[1,i+1] = dt_main.Columns[i].Caption; }

  for (int i = 0; i < dt_main.Rows.Count; i++) // Fill in data
  { for (int j = 0; j < dt_main.Columns.Count; j++)
    { xlWorkSheet.Cells[i+2,j+1] = dt_main.Rows[i][j]; } }

  // For working with AutoFill, I need a source and a destination range.
  Range rng_Source = xlWorkSheet.Cells;
  Range rng_Destination = rng_Source;
  rng_Destination.Resize(rng_Source.Rows.Count + 1);
  rng_Source.AutoFill(rng_Destination,XlAutoFillType.xlFillDefault);
#endregion
```

As you can see, the idea is quite simple:

- Fill the temporary Excel worksheet with data from the `DataTable` (the column titles are just there for debugging purposes).
- Define the source and destination ranges. The destination range is the source range, extended with one row.
- Perform the Autofill.

I'm having some issues with the whole idea:

Current questions:

- The `Resize()` method can't be used as a method.
  How can I define my destination range?
- How can I debug this code?
  `rng_Source` is shown as a `System._ComObject`, so is `rng_Source[1,1]`, how can I see the values?

Future questions:

- My application is enormously slow, which seems to be a known problem. However, using `OfficeOpenXml` reference seems not to be a good solution, because I doubt that this reference handles the `AutoFill` feature. (Am I correct, saying this?)
- As I seem to be doomed to continue working with the `Interop` reference, does anybody know about a faster way to load a `DataTable` into an `Interop` Worksheet?

Can somebody help me out here? (The current questions are the ones, blocking my development)

Comment: Aside from the sizable technical issues you've created for yourself, this would also rely on the autofill algorithms for Excel not changing in such a way that it breaks your data processing (or at least makes it unpredictable). I know Excel's autofill is really clever and impressive and all that, but are you sure your data needs don't happen to be simple enough that you could implement your own algorithm(s) for it depending on your data? Things like numerical interpolation (given 1, 3, 5, predict the next one is 7) aren't hard, and you could add more bags of tricks as you go along.

Comment: The cases of identical values are arithmetic progression are already covered by my own algorithm. I'm interested in the cases like "AB12", "AB13", "AB14" => calculate "AB15". I'm also already searching for A.I.-based prediction systems. The Excel approach is an intermediate approach.

Comment: Then I'd use the slowness and awkwardness as motivation for accelerating the search, rather than directing any energy towards optimizing this, because yes, automation is not fast or convenient (and it's the only way of doing it, as Excel's algorithms are proprietary and only available from a running instance of Excel). I don't know if AI is required as such; the case you mention can be handled by splitting the value on a regex for numbers (`\d+`) and checking if the interpolation can be applied to each digit group so detected. A little more involved, sure, but no neurons needed.